# Return list of generic implementations possible

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have the following interface:

```
public interface Query<TModel>
{
    IList<TModel> GetData();
}
```

I would like to have some service that can return all the queries implementations:

```
public interface IQueryProvider
{
   List<Query<>> GetAllQueries();
}
```

and then be able to call GetData on one:

```
var queries = provider.GetAllQueries();
var results = queries[0].GetData();
```

Would it be possible to achieve this with generics?

Comment: What Type do you want for `results` ?

Comment: @Henk That will depend on each Query implementation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use the open generic type `Query<>`, except inside `typeof()`. If you wanted to refer to a set of queries (type not specified) you would need a non-generic API, for example:

```
public interface IQuery {
     IList GetData();
     Type QueryType { get; }
}
public interface IQuery<TModel> : IQuery
{
    new IList<TModel> GetData();
}    
public interface IQueryProvider
{
   List<IQuery> GetAllQueries();
}
```

this, however, means you need to provide a shadow implementation of `IQuery` for each, which is a pain. Note there is also an ambiguity in the above if any service implements both `IQuery<Foo>` and `IQuery<Bar>` - in that there is no obvious way of indicating `QueryType`.

Answer (score 0):

Your IQueryProvider has to know what generic type IQuery is using. There are 2 solutions I can think of.

Solution 1: Define a generic type when you create the IQueryProvider instance

```
public interface IQueryProvider<TModel>
{
    List<IQuery<TModel>> GetAllQueries();
}
```

Solution 2: Pass in the type in the method

```
public interface IQueryProvider
{
    List<IQuery<TModel>> GetAllQueries<TModel>();
}
```

Also, I suggest you to change Query to IQuery for standard naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

If you throw out `IList<>` and replace it with `IEnumerable<>` you can make your interface covariant. Unfortunately there is no `ReadOnlyList<>` or `ReadOnlyCollection<>` interface(No idea what MS was thinking there).

```
public interface Query<out TModel>
{
    IEnumerable<TModel> GetData();
}

public interface IQueryProvider
{
   List<Query<object>> GetAllQueries();
}
```

Note that this will only work for reference type `TModel`s.